# How to get unlimited queries with a curl operation?

Tags: curl

I am trying to get data using CURL function from other websites, like google backlinks, yahoo index pages, whois info etc. but after 5-10 queries my IP or my server IP is blocked and it shows no value. Here's the Curl function I am using:

```
function getPage ($url) {
if (function_exists("curl_init")) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
return curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
} else {
return file_get_contents($url);
}
}
```

Help me to get unlimited queries from Google, Yahoo and sowm whois website. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use YQL for this !

examples
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/54673.aspx

UPD

just look at source code  https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

There is also webconsole where you can test any queries - let's download current page =)

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3Dyhoo%22#h=select%20%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/7253665/file-get-contents-unlimited-queries-how-to/7268078%23comment-8764764%22
```

code examples with php http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_php

**But read carefully documentation - nothing is perfect and YQL have limitations**

Comment: Hello Fivell, This http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ looks good but how do i implement in my php, i mean, i need full code as I am not much familiar with YQL. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you Fivell for all the links. I will try my best to get these things, i hope i'll get what i need atm :)